# For $a,b,c>0$, prove that: $(ab+bc+ca)(\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{1}{(c+a)^2})\ge \frac{9}{4}$

Tags: inequality

For $a,b,c>0$, prove that: $$(ab+bc+ca)(\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{1}{(c+a)^2})\ge \frac{9}{4}$$

The sample solution is:

- $f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{1}{(c+a)^2}$
- Normalize $ab+bc+ca=1$, assuming $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$, we can prove $f(a,b,c)\ge f(t,t,c)$ with $t$ satisfy $t^2+2tc=1$
- With $c=\frac{1-t^2}{2t}$ we can prove $f(t,t,c)\ge \frac{9}{4}$, which is equivalent to $\frac{(1-t^2)(1-3t^2)^2}{4t^2(1+t^2)}\ge0 $

My question:

- Why $f(a,b,c)\ge f(t,t,c)$? Can you help me explain?
- I know this is a very famous problem and there are many solutions to it, but I am doing it with another method (I really don't know the name of this method, simply say we need to reduce the number of variable from $3$ variables $a,b,c$ to $2$ variables $t,c$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OEHFE0FLjYLBJJ5QgXomhtuG6N34psrc/view) will help you a lot. This is taken from [the Canadian IMO Training Camp website](https://sites.google.com/site/imocanada/winter-camps). For your first step, note that $(t+c)^2 = (a+c)(b+c)$. It needs some more calculation, which is on the link I gave you above.

Comment: I think I can understand where I'm stuck. I try to express $t$ "specifically" like $t=\sqrt{ab}$ or sth like that but that would be an ugly expression. It should be that $(t+c)^2=(a+c)(b+c)$